# Handling I/O in a bash script that executes another shell instance

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script that executes a series of commands.  One of them is a application that itself creates a shell.  How can I get my bash script to execute commands within that subshell?

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
command1
command2
someapp
command3
command4
```

"someapp" is essentially a bash shell (provided by a vendor - outside my control), but it appears to spawn the shell in another process while the spawner waits.  That causes the bash script to wait on someapp until the shell is closed, then it executes commands 3 and 4.  I want those commands to execute within the someapp shell.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Does someapp take arguments or act on stdin? If not, you may have to interact with someapp using [Expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Are you worried about haveing too many spawned sub-shells? And/OR do you you want someapp to receive input genereated by command3,4? A little more detail would help

Comment: someapp acts only on stdin. It basically is a shell:
<pre>
> someapp
XYZ environment shell
%
</pre>
So I want command3 and 4 to be executed on THAT shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most shells take a `-c` argument that allows a command to be specified.  From the bash man page:

> -c string 
>   If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string. If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.

and ...

> -s 
>   If the -s option is present, or if no arguments remain after option processing, then commands are read from the standard input. This option allows the positional parameters to be set when invoking an interactive shell.

Thus, I'd try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
command1
command2
someapp -c "command3 ; command4"
```

OR

```
#!/bin/bash
command1
command2
someapp -s <<-EOF
    command3
    command4
    EOF
```